# Execute multiple SSH Commands from Bash on remote Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, automation, key

Hi I have 3 Docker containers A, B and C. I need to execute a .sh file embedded in A which should go something like this:

```
!#/bin/bash
ssh root@containerIP "mkdir /path/to/dir"
ssh root@containerIP "touch someFile.txt"
....
```

My Dockerfiles for B & C are:

```
FROM node
RUN apt-get update
# RUN apk add --update --no-cache openssh
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
WORKDIR /home/debian
COPY ./ /home/debian
RUN git init
RUN git clone --branch master https://github.com/SamLProgrammer/LAB1SD.git
WORKDIR /home/debian/LAB1SD
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

and Dockerfile for middleware A is:

```
FROM node
RUN apt-get update
WORKDIR /home/debian
COPY ./ /home/debian
RUN git init
RUN git clone --branch another https://github.com/SamLProgrammer/DockerMiddlewareLab1.git
WORKDIR /home/debian/DockerMiddlewareLab1
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

My problem is that I dont know the remote servers (B & C) ssh key. And all the process needs to be automated.

So, as far as I know, creating an ssh key-gen is not an option since it generates a ssh key on remote servers (B & C) and then I need to copy that key file in the "Middleware Server" (A). but in the proces I will be asked for (A) ssh password which I wont be able to input manually because of not having access to B & C terminals.

That's why Im thinking of creating a .txt file which contains the ssh key for (B & C) before I run the Docker Images as Containers and set it as their key, so my middleware (A) can know that ssh key and execute SSH commands using sshpass or something like that.

How can I achieve this? how can I set the ssh key from a .txt file when I run the docker Images?.
Or am I planning this in a very wrong way? and what would be the correct one to achieve making those ssh commands autmoated just by calling the bash in my situation?

I'm fairly noob at these automation infrastructures workarounds, any suggestion would help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: If you need the application in container A to create a file, writing something like an HTTP endpoint in the Node application would be a better approach.  Docker isn't usually used as automation infrastructure; tools like Chef, Salt Stack, or Ansible are more typical.

Comment: .txt file which contains key is already created, and it would be copied into docker container when it runs but then generate an ssh-key from that copied file into the remote container.